# Running exe files on server side on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have exe file which requires json data as an input and returns xml data, and how can i run it from rails application and later get those xml data from this exe file?

Comment: does the exe take json as an argument? or does it take it through stdin? is this something which should be kicked off on a http request and finished before the response is returned? or do you want this to happen in the background, asynchronously?

Comment: through stdin, this file should be started after ajax request and when it finishes(returns xml) it should turn off itselfs. So i get json data from client by ajax request and later run this exe file and get xml data

Comment: If you want to open an executable and handle stdin/stdout with it, you should use popen3 in the [open3 module](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Open3.html). If the executable takes a while to run, you'll have to run it as a background job, using [active jobs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html). The job will have to store the xml somewhere where you can access it next time someone requests it. You could use [redis](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) if it's small data. Or you could just stick it in your database.

Comment: Give all that a shot. If you get stuck, update your question with code samples and the error you're getting, and we'll be happy to help you. The question you posed us so far is far too general and ambiguous for us to tackle.